# Python Shell stuck when it reaches certain method that checks for items in a list

Tags: python, list

I have a method that is supposed to determine if a specific value is inside the list, if the value is in the list, it will return `True` and `False` if it isn't. When the program reaches that method, the shell is just blank.

I have tried altering the `elif` statements and going line by line to see where the issue could be. I tested the method by just returning True and the program works fine.

```
class advisor(person):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def approveSelectedCourse(self, finishedCourses, theClass):
        if theClass in finishedCourses:
            return False
        elif theClass is 213:
            if 110 in finishedCourses:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        elif theClass is 412:
            if 316 in finishedCourses:
                return True
            else:
                return False

class student(person):
    def __init__(self, name, stuID, finishedCourses, selectedCourses):
        person.__init__(self, name)
        self.stuID = stuID
        self.selectedCourses = selectedCourses
        self.finishedCourses = finishedCourses
```

The result should return True if the specific class is inside the finishedCourses list.

Comment: Do you know the size of the "list"?  (side note: you can `return 110 in finishedCoures` instead of `elif`

Comment: Don't use `is` when you really mean `==`.

Comment: if `theClass` is not in the `finishedCourses` list and different from `213` and `412` the function will return a `None` because you didn't handle that case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `is` where you mean `==`; there's no guarantee that the variable `theClass` and the literal 412, for example, both refer the same *object* representing 412.

```
>>> theClass = 412
>>> theClass is 412
False
>>> theClass == 412
True
```

The fact that this *is* true for 213

```
>>> theClass = 213
>>> theClass is 213
True
```

is the consequence of a particular optimization employed by the CPython implementation (and possibly others) for *small* integers, not a language guarantee.

```
def approveSelectedCourse(self, finishedCourses, theClass):
    if theClass in finishedCourses:
        return False
    elif theClass == 213:
        if 110 in finishedCourses:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    elif theClass == 412:
        if 316 in finishedCourses:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

which can be simplified to

```
def approveSelectedCourse(self, finishedCourses, theClass):
    if theClass in finishedCourses:
        return False
    elif theClass == 213:
        return 110 in finishedCourses
    elif theClass == 412:
        return 316 in finishedCourses
```